# Using Parameters at different points within For Each Loop Container

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, ssis, execute-sql-task

I have the following steps within the Control Flow, where WorkOrderID is used by the first Execute SQL task and InvoiceID used by the second script task.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong below as it is failing on the Update Invoice Status object?

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "Update     I  Set
>     I.Status = CASE WHEN C1.Name = 'Cy..." failed with the following
>   error: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each
>   OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.". Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.

and the query for the Update Invoice Status object is:

```
Update
    I
 Set
    I.Status = 10
from
    Invoice I 
where 
    I.ID  = ?
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not what with what we have. *Maybe* the scope variable(s) is wrong?

Comment: @Philip what are the SQL statment you are using?

Comment: @Hadi just put it into the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu - will check. Thanks

Comment: Why `Update    I Set    I.Status = 10 from    Invoice I where     I.ID  = ?` instead of `UPDATE Invoice SET Status = 10 WHERE ID = ?`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of all Execute SQL Task Tabs

Comment: @Hadi - will be adding some extra join statements later.

Comment: i think the parameter name is causing the issue , it must be `0` instead of `1`. check my answer update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Checking data types and parameter names / order

I think that the error is caused by the Variable data type. Check that `User::WorkerID` is of type `VARCHAR` while it must be integer. Check that the data type of variable are relevant to the column.

Based on the following article [Resolving an SSIS Error Due to Parameters Not Mapped Correctly](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/1/20/resolving-an-ssis-error-due-to-parameters-not-mapped-correct.html):

> Other reasons this particular error could come up is if your Data Type is set incorrectly, or if the number of query parameters don’t match the variables mapped (and in the correct order).

**Also why InvoiceID parameter name is `1` instead of `0`? Try change it back to `0`**

---

## Workaround

You can use Expression to build SQL Statement if you still have problems with parameters:

Go to Expression in the `Execute SQL Task` editor. Select the `SQLStatmentSource` property and write a similar expression:

```
"Update
    I
Set
    I.Status = 10
from
    Invoice I 
where 
    I.ID  = " + (DT_WSTR,50)@[User::InvoiceID]
```

Comment: WorkOrderID is of type "String".

Comment: And InvoiceID of type `LONG` or `Int`

Comment: @Philip can you show the real sql statemet `Update I Set I.Status = CASE WHEN C1.Name = 'Cy ..` and provide scrennshot of the first form in Execute SQL Task

Comment: InvoiceID is LONG

Comment: @Philip Also why `InvoiceID` parameter name is `1` instead of `0`

Comment: ahh geez, thanks for that. Very simple miss in the end.